# How do I measure the (near) infra-red radiation intensity?

Tags: optics, photons, infrared-radiation

I need to measure how much of the radiation is absorbed by a specific fabric (as in "what percentage of photons is absorbed"). I am interested in 2 LEDs: 650nm (red) and 800nm (infra-red).

The trivial solution is to illuminate a [photosensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodetector) with the LED with and without fabric between them and see how much is absorbed.

The problem is that commercially available [sensors](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B075DC6X25) measure [*luminous* flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_flux) rather than [*radiant* flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_flux). This means that such sensors should work for the *red* LED but not for the *infra-red* one.
Also, *ideally*, I would actually prefer to know the radiation energy in Watts, not just the absorption percentage.

My questions are:

1. Maybe I am missing something and the device I am looking for is in fact available for purchase? (for <\$100)
2. I am sure any university optics lab has such a device (as well as more advanced equipment, e.g., а [spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_spectrometer)). It is probably not used all the time. I live in NYC, maybe someone with access to the equipment in the area could help me do the measurements?

Comment: I don't get it. You will just need a sensor that measures the light. Then you measure with and without sample giving the fraction of absorbed radiation. Knowledge if the power of your source does the rest.

Comment: @my2cts: luminous flux of IR LED is 0, so this will _NOT_ work with 800nm.

Comment: What is important if your sensor gives a signal.

Comment: @my2cts: yes, and it will give 0 signal for IR because its luminous flux is 0 because it is outside of the visible spectrum.

Comment: Sensors usually don't care about textbook definitions. Point your source at the sensor and check if there is a signal.

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://ipvm.com/reports/how-to-measure-ir-illumination